# JAVA Clone() or Serializable for copying objects with a bunch of object/String variables?

Tags: java, serialization, clone

I have a class Individual and it has a bunch of objects references to other classes. Those classes themselves have bunch of object references to other classes. Something like this:

```
Class Individual{
ArrayList<Segment> seg;
float fitness;
float coverage;
}

Class Segment{
ArrayList<Event> events;
String curr_activity;
Event curr_event;
}

Class Event{
String dest_activity;
String event;
String event_type;
}
```

I wanna create a deep copy of a reference to Class Individual. What would be the best way to do it ? Should I use Serializable or clone() ? I tried using clone but it throws CloneNotSupportedException. Any good suggestions ?

Comment: Whatever the way you choose, if you don't read the exception and the javadoc of the methods you're using, you won't get far. The best way would be to avoid making a copy in the first place, by making your classes immutable. The second best way would be to use a copy constructor.

Comment: Sorry, but I have a list of objects for Individual class as well and I need to get a random individual from that list, make some changes to it and add it back to the list without affecting the previous elements. Should I try using copy constructor then ?

Comment: I stand by everything I've said before. I'd prefer immutable classes. If really not possible, a copy constructor.